# Recharts : Position label in center of pie slice

Tags: reactjs, pie-chart, recharts

I'm pretty new to React so please bear with me

I created a pie chart using Recharts, with custom labels, but I cannot get each label to position itself in the center of its slice. See, for instance, the numbers "20" and "11" in the [image]

My code currently looks as follows (the embarrassing truth is most of this comes from samples I f found online)

```
 <PieChart width={400} height={240} style={{ outline: "none" }}>
      <Pie
        data={data}
        dataKey="value"
        innerRadius={50}
        outerRadius={100}
        labelLine={false}
        label={customDonutLabel}
        style={{ outline: "none" }}
      />
      <Tooltip content={<ChartTooltip />} />
    </PieChart>


const customDonutLabel: PieLabel<CustomDonutLabelRenderProps<ChartDataProps>> = (props) => {
  const slicePercentage = props.payload.value * 100;
  if (slicePercentage < 10) {
    return null;
  }
  const RADIAN = Math.PI / 180;
  const innerRadius = convertToNumber(props.innerRadius);
  const outerRadius = convertToNumber(props.outerRadius);
  const cx = convertToNumber(props.cx);
  const cy = convertToNumber(props.cy);
  const midAngle = convertToNumber(props.midAngle);

  const radius = innerRadius + (outerRadius - innerRadius) * 0.35;
  const x = cx + radius * Math.cos(-midAngle * RADIAN);
  const y = cy + radius * Math.sin(-midAngle * RADIAN);

  return (
    <text
      style={{ fontWeight: "semibold", fontSize: "md" }}
      x={x}
      y={y}
      fill={props.payload.color}
      textAnchor={x > cx ? "start" : "end"}
      dominantBaseline="central"
    >
      {Math.round(props.payload.value * 100)}
    </text>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have done the job

```
  const outerRadius = convertToNumber(props.outerRadius);
  const cx = convertToNumber(props.cx);
  const cy = convertToNumber(props.cy);
  const midAngle = convertToNumber(props.midAngle);

  const RADIAN = Math.PI / 180;
  const radius = innerRadius + (outerRadius - innerRadius) * 0.7;

  return (
    <text
      style={{ fontWeight: "semibold", fontSize: "md" }}
      x={cx + radius * Math.cos(-midAngle * RADIAN)}
      y={cy + radius * Math.sin(-midAngle * RADIAN)}
      fill={props.payload.color}
      textAnchor="middle"
      dominantBaseline="middle"
    >
      {Math.round(props.payload.value * 100)}
    </text>
  );
```

Comment: What were the relevant changes? Also, I have very similar code, but for the radius, I'm multiplying by 0.5 -- so 0.5 and 0.7 seem like they might be "magic" numbers instead of something more dynamic.